# Adding data to a column and append it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a input data in a file input.txt. I want to add 200 with each row of 4th column and want to append just beside to it in the format same as original.

Input.txt

```
>   >   >
0.000   5.064   -0.15835E-01 -7.755619582136471027e-03
0.700   9.064   -0.21715E-02 -1.302134466433525067e-02
0.800   5.064   0.18954E-01 -1.691809184964498253e-02
>   >   >
0.500   4.977   0.32899E-02 1.439701445411046415e-02
0.200   6.977   0.15972E-01 6.094966468334198084e-03
0.700   4.977   0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03
```

out.txt

```
>   >   >
0.000   5.064   -0.15835E-01 -7.755619582136471027e-03 199.99224438041787
0.700   9.064   -0.21715E-02 -1.302134466433525067e-02 199.98697865533566
0.800   5.064   0.18954E-01 -1.691809184964498253e-02  199.98308190815035
>   >   >
0.500   4.977   0.32899E-02 1.439701445411046415e-02   200.01439701445412
0.200   6.977   0.15972E-01 6.094966468334198084e-03   200.00609496646834
0.700   4.977   0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03  199.99435955454683
```

I tried :

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('input.txt')
data1=data(:,3)+200
```

I am getting error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '>'`
I hope some expert will help me overcoming this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have non-numeric symbols in the file. You can treat them as comments:

```
data = np.loadtxt('input.txt', comments=">")
```

But then you will not be able to preserve them in the output file. I am afraid your only option is to read the file line by line in a loop:

```
CHANGE = 200
with open('input.txt') as infile, open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.startswith('>'): # Needs a modification
            parts = line.split()
            parts.append(str(float(parts[3]) + CHANGE) + '\n')
            line = ' '.join(parts)
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Hii @DYZ i want to the last column to be seen in the output file i mean there must be original file plus one extra column of output file....so that in the output file there must be 5 column instead of four...please suggest

Comment: This is _not_ what you asked for in the original post. However, the new file out.txt has five columns. Simply rename it to input.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand the question but I think I know what the problem is. There are a couple ways I may be able to help you:

- Remove the `>`s at the beginning of the file.
- Skip over the `>`s. Like this:

```py
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("temporaryfile.txt", "w") as temp:
        temp.write(f.read().replace(">   >   >",""))
    
    
data=np.loadtxt("temporaryfile.txt")
data1=data(:,3)+200
```

and just use `import os;os.remove("temporaryfile.txt")` to remove `temporaryfile.txt` afterward.

The problem is its running into those `>`s and that is what is causing the error. So, if you remove those, that should fix your problem.

Comment: i need to append the addition and save it to a file....can  please suggest how to do it

Comment: As suggested in the answer, remove the `>` programmatically and then you can easily read the data into a pandas data frame. Later create a new column that adds 200 to the last column...then save it as a text/csv file.

Comment: Note that, according to OP, the "> > >" things must stay in the output file.

Comment: @Priya can u please suggest a solution for the same....

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this without creating a new file and do the operation inplace using **fileinput** library. In the blow code it is preserving this ">" character too.

```
import sys
import fileinput

file = fileinput.input('test.txt', inplace=1)

for i, line in enumerate(file):
    if line.startswith('>'):
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    else:
        string = line.split()
        string.append('200\n')
        line = ' '.join(string)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
file.close()
```

output of above code:

```
>   >   >
0.700 4.977 0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03 200
0.700 4.977 0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03 200
0.700 4.977 0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03 200
>   >   >
0.700 4.977 0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03 200
0.700 4.977 0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03 200
0.700 4.977 0.30631E-01 -5.640445453166963163e-03 200
```

Comment: Thanks @sdpshaw...however i want to do some operation like fourier transform to the last column of the test.txt and want to append the the result to the last column instead of 200.can it be possible...please suggest a solution.